# table weight vs destination

Tags: shipping-methods, table-rates

when i select one quantity then work correct when i select one more quantity of one product then work not correct.

```
   Country  Region/State    Zip/Postal Code Weight (and above)  Shipping Price
    NZL       auk             *             1                     0
    NZL       auk             *             2                     3
    NZL       auk             *             3                     5
    NZL       auk             *             4                     10
```

Comment: What's the weight of the product?

Comment: 1 kg when i select 3 quantity then answer are 15

Comment: weight is calculated by `qty` * weight attribute. So if it says `1` it should be `3`. What kind of product is it and could it be a 3th party module / custom code that is changing weight

Comment: Well I'm not using any third party module or any other extension all this is being done by the default Magento functionality.
The problem is that I'm getting qty * weight * shipping price as the total shipping cost, instead of which I need to get the shipping cost which must be charged on the qty * weight..